# Save C binary tree root value in variable

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

Im working on a C library for binary tree, and Im wondering how I could save the value of the root of the tree to be able to display it later in a function.

My tree struct:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

typedef struct Node TNode;
typedef struct Node *binary_tree;
```

The binary tree root is initialised with the 3 value like this:

caller:

```
tree = NewBinaryTree(3);
```

NewBinaryTree method:

```
binary_tree NewBinaryTree(int value_root) {
    binary_tree newRoot = malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    if (newRoot) {
        newRoot->value = value_root;
        newRoot->left = NULL;
        newRoot->right = NULL;
    }
    return newRoot;
}
```

Basically I would like to be able to do a function that just display the value_root function even after adding elements to the binary tree and be able to still display the value_root value.This might be very basic but im learning C and im not sure.

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question corretly; would it be an option to save the return value of `NewBinaryTree` somewhere else to refer to it later?

Comment: In the caller: `printf( "%d\n", tree->value )`

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking, but perhaps `if(tree) printf("left=%p data=%d right=%p\n", (void*)tree->left, tree->value, (void*)tree->right);`

Comment: @Codor Yes well just the value of the "root" of the binary tree(3 in this case).Because afterwards I add element to the binary tree and I want to be able to just display the root (3 value) later on

Comment: @user3386109 Exactly! thank you!

Comment: See: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — succinctly, the answer is No.

Answer (score 0):

In the caller: `printf( "%d\n", tree->value )`
                    – user3386109